# jtable take time to display data from db

Tags: java, sql, database, jtable, populate

I am reading data from SQL database and displaying it in a Jtable; then I am adding other columns and doing some calculations... The display time of data in Jtable is long even if the number of rows is low. Any hint pleaaaase?

```
    public  JTable display () throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ParseException{   
        java.sql.Connection sqlConnection = null;
        sqlConnection = getSQLConnection();
        Statement stmt = null;
        stmt = sqlConnection.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT OFINTERNE,CMDCLIENT,CHAINE,REF,QTE,QTEBAC,DELAI,EFFECTIF,RENDEMENT,TPSn,"
                + "dateCreation,QTEPROD,datedebutpce,datedebutbac,datefinpce,termine from TEST_LAMIAA where OFINTERNE<3000 "
                + "order by chaine");

        ResultSetMetaData rsmetaData = rs.getMetaData();

        //stores the number of columns
        int colmns = rsmetaData.getColumnCount();

        // the object that will pass data to the jTable 
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();

        Vector cl_names = new Vector();
        Vector data_rows = new Vector();

        for(int i = 1; i<(colmns+1); i++){
        cl_names.addElement(rsmetaData.getColumnName(i));

        }
        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(cl_names);
        while(rs.next()){
            data_rows = new Vector();
        for(int j = 1; j <(colmns+1) ; j++){
            data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
//            System.out.println(rs.getString(j));
        }
                dtm.addRow(data_rows);
        }
        //pass default model object into my table 

         jTable1.setModel(dtm);
        //adding columns

        TableColumn col = new TableColumn(dtm.getColumnCount() - 1);
        col.setHeaderValue("Sequence");
        jTable1.addColumn(col);
        dtm.addColumn(col);

        TableColumn date = new TableColumn(dtm.getColumnCount() - 1);
        date.setHeaderValue("Date");
        jTable1.addColumn(date);
        dtm.addColumn(date);

         TableColumn duree = new TableColumn(dtm.getColumnCount() - 1);
        duree.setHeaderValue("Duree");
        jTable1.addColumn(duree);
        dtm.addColumn(duree);

        TableColumn datFin = new TableColumn(dtm.getColumnCount() - 1);
        datFin.setHeaderValue("Date Fin");
        jTable1.addColumn(datFin);
        dtm.addColumn(datFin);

   jTable1.setModel(dtm);

       return jTable1;
   }
```

Comment: Please post some code. We can't help you without seeing what you're doing at the moment.

Comment: This is my function that I call in a button action to display the information in the Jtable... I also included other calculations in this function

Comment: First step: identify which part is slow: the SQL statement or your Java code. Run the query in your favorite SQL client and see how long it takes (ideally run it with `explain (analyze, verbose)`

Comment: The sql query takes 9 secs to display 10 records which is quite slow but I think the code is the slowest part because when I run the program it takes time to display results in the output box and more time to display it to the JTable